# Symfonyで開発を始めるにあたってどのバージョンを使うのがよいか？

Tags: php, symfony2

これからSymfonyを使ってアプリケーション開発を始めたいと考えています。

[公式サイトのダウンロードページ](http://symfony.com/download)をみると2.6と2.3の2つのバージョンがダウンロード可能になっていますが、バージョンの古い2.3の方がサポート期間が長くなっています。

どちらのバージョンを利用して開発を始めるのが良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flied onionさんの回答にもあるように、

> どのバージョンを選択すべきかはプロジェクトが何を重きに置くかになるとは思います

が重要だと思います。

たとえば、2015年3月以降も運用するプロジェクトであれば 2.6系で開発しつつ 
2.7が出れば(2015年3月予定)アップデートするのが良いと思います。

数ヶ月だけのキャンペーンサイトの構築などであれば 2.3 でも全然問題ないと思います。

リリーススケジュールについては公式サイトの [The Release Process ページ](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html)で確認できます。
今のところほぼスケジュールどおりにリリースされています。

また、2.4以降でなければ利用できない機能も多々あります。
たとえば、2.6からは[セキュリティコンポーネントも使いやすくなっています。](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements)

そして、何よりも気をつけるべきことはバージョンによって利用できる or できない ということがあるので、
まずは参照するドキュメントのバージョンの確認を忘れないことです。

オンラインドキュメントでも右上で対応バージョンを切り替えできますので、お忘れなく。
おすすめは[公式サイト Documentation ページ](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html)下部から Offline Documentation で PDF をダウンロードしてしまうことです。

Answer (score 1):

2.3はLTS（Long Term Support）なので、2.6よりもサポート期間が長いようですね。

こちらで確認すると、2.7 (現在開発バージョン）は次期LTSの用です。

http://symfony.com/roadmap?version=2.7#checker

> Symfony 2.7 will be a long term support version published in May 2015.

内部の変更まではわかりませんが、

2.3は現状安定板がリリースされている中ではサポート期間が長いですね。またリリースして期間が長いのでノウハウの蓄積も多いと思います。

2.7は 3年間(予定ではMay 2018まで)bug fixとその後 1年間（May 2019のsecurity fix）サポートが予定されているようです。
(なお、通常リリースは1年間のbug fix、その後1年のsecurity fixのサポートの様です。)

しかし2.7はまだリリース予定日までも時間がありますので、2.6にて開発を行い2.7にマイグレートするという考え方もあると思います。

どのバージョンを選択すべきかはプロジェクトが何を重きに置くかになるとは思いますが、参考までに。